# Does db.ListProperty act like set() in avoiding duplicate keys?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a model with a property called tags of type db.ListProperty(db.Key). The app will be adding new tags to the entities and it is possible that added tags already exist as part of the list.

```
class Entity(db.Model):
  tags = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

How does app engine handle those? Are duplicates avoided? Or do we have to do something like:

`entity.tags = list(set(entity.tags.extend(new_tags_list)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `ListProperty` does not deduplicate - it would be a violation of its implied contract as a list if it did. Here's [a straightforward implementation of a SetProperty](https://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon/blob/master/__init__.py#L337).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [`ListProperty` implementation](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py#3382), it doesn't looks like it is doing anything special to the list beside validation, you should be able to implement your own `SetProperty`based on this.

Comment: Thanks proppy. So you would subclass ListProperty in your models file and override validate? Or would you do it in another way?

Comment: Subclassing make sense if you want to use this kind of property in multiple model, otherwise your workaround looks straightforward if it is only used in one place.